# .PNG Images from MipMap Folder Not Scaling on Tablets

Tags: android, android-studio, png, mipmaps

I have recently read that Google now allows references from the mipmap folders instead of the drawables for regular image assets. From my understanding, mipmap folders were previously used for icons only but are now capable of rendering high-quality images.

I have a resume creator app, and my resume examples are .PNG files. I am trying to ensure that the files are displayed properly on the appropriate tablet sizes. I have added image files to the mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-xhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi, and mipmap-xxxhdpi folders respectively. Unfortunately, the images are scaling on smaller phones and the 7" tablet, but I cannot seem to get the image to scale on the 10" tablet. Below are screenshots of the rendering for both the 7" tablet and the 10" tablet:

7" tablet:

[image]

10" tablet (Google Nexus 10 Emulator):

[image]

I have also included my folders:

[image]

Comment: Does the behavior change if you put the PNGs in the drawable-* folders? The only real reason to use the mipmap folder is if you are performing resource optimizations that strip resources for unused screen densities.

Comment: I actually have mirrored the mipmap and drawable folders to have the same image sizes. The reference in my code is to the mipmap folder, i.e. R.mipmap.resume_one.png.

Comment: And just to be clear. The images in the different folders are different sizes correct?

Comment: I have revised to include my image folders

Answer (score 1):

Images won't scale automatically.  You have to tell them to.

But the best answer is more about screen size and pixel density.  If you look into the "drawables" folder, there are a series of other folders, all named for large, med, small, xlarge, etc...  You should have an image for each appropriate screen size.  The device will choose the best one to use automatically.

This means if you have an image that looks good on your 1024px tablet.  You should have an identical image in the smaller folder that is 800px.  And so on...

Comment: So in other words, particular devices support different image qualities? I guess I am confused as to why the 7" rendered appropriately but not the 10".

Comment: Do they have the exact same filename?

Comment: And you're sure they are all different sizes?

Comment: Is this only on the emulator, or the physical device?

Comment: It appears in this way on both emulator and device.

Comment: I just realized that if I open Google Nexus 7 5.1 with that has a different minimum API, it renders a different folder and does not generate an image that fills the screen. Any idea why this may be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Upon reading your discussion with durbnpoisn, i found out that it has same problem with me. Sometimes your app does not get the right images in your drawable folder. To do so you can do it programmatically. Below is the sample code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
float widthDpi = metrics.xdpi;
float heightDpi = metrics.ydpi;
float widthInches = widthPixels / widthDpi;
float heightInches = heightPixels / heightDpi;
double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt((widthInches * widthInches) + (heightInches * heightInches)); // this code returns the actual screen size (eg. 7,8,9,10 inches in double format ex: 7.932189832)
diagonalInches = (double) Math.round(diagonalInches * 10) / 10; // round up to first decimal places



if (diagonalInches >= 7 && diagonalInches <=8){
    //set image here
} else {
    //set image here
}
```